# How to navigate to home?

Tags: angular

I have problem to navigate to home route.
When i do this its working in html:

```
<a href="/"><i class="icon-power"></i></a></li>
```

But when i do this and call a method:

```
logout(){
        this.api.logout('/logout-user').subscribe((r:any)=>{});
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
```

I need to call service before navigate. But this is not working. Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: You can put your navigate in the subscribe block

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}

logout(){
    this.api.logout('/logout-user').subscribe((r:any)=>{
        // after the api call user will be redirected to home page
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        // OR
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    });
}
```

Comment: Argument of type '"/"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.

Comment: i already try that...in my question...i dont care about response in service

Comment: If this answer isn’t working for you, you might have implemented something incredibly wrong in your service call and the next() never gets called -> navigate never gets called.

Comment: foreget about service router.navigate['/']) is not redirect to home page

Comment: @None, please check updated answer and confirm those are same as minw.

Comment: its same...nothing happend...its not redirect me

Comment: @None, will you please create a demo on stackblitz.com, that would be very helpful to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer of Vivek Doshi does not solve your problem, then you should check that you redirect the path "" to "home".

Routes example:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
  { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent },  
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" }
];
```